# Is it possible to share my position to another device (secured)?

Tags: android-studio, location, mapbox, share

I try to share my position to another secured device like my second phone. **I use MapBox and AndroidStudio** and I'm able to see my position but only from my phone. I try to find a solution that helps me in my problem. So I want to know if it's possible to do that.

Sincerely, Tony

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @Tony 
I have googled that quickly and I hope that you can find these helpful https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7326816?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en
https://support.google.com/trustedcontacts/answer/7227922?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are new here. I would recommend you not to ask questions about problems that you have not yet properly researched on your own.

It would help if you could share at least your thoughts on how you would approach this task. Also, make sure to answer specific questions. Otherwise you will get unspecific answers, like the one below.

**Now to your problem:**

This definitely is possible and there are many ways to accomplish this. The approaches to accomplish this depend on means to your disposal. Do you have a webserver that you can utilize? Or would you like to transmit the position directly from one device to another?

**Via Webserver:**

Create Webserver side script that listens to HTTP POST requests and writes the POST parameter (your position) to a database/file.
Create a second script that will answer a request for this position.

Call script 1 with Device 1, that wants to share its position.
Call script 2 with Device 2, that wants to read position.

Display position on map in application on Device 2.

**Direct, one device to another:**

You could even send your position via text message, and make your mobile application read the message, then display the position on a map.